# How can I check that Tcl command didn't throw an exception or error?

Tags: tcl

I have a following procedure:

```
proc myexec { args } {
    info_msg "Executing shell command: $args"

    set catch_res [catch  {eval exec $args} res]

    if { $catch_res != 0 } {
        error_msg "Failed in command: $args"
        error_msg "$res"
    }

    return $catch_res
}
```

It only checks Unix commands and doesn't work with Tcl commands.
How can I change this procedure so that it will work with Tcl commands?

For example, if I want to check that the following commands evaluate without error:

```
set object1 $object2
```

or

```
open $filename r
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method is to do this:

```
proc myeval { args } {
    info_msg "Executing Tcl command: $args"

    set catch_res [catch $args res]

    if { $catch_res != 0 } {
        error_msg "Failed in command: $args"
        error_msg "$res"
    }

    return $res
}
```

Here, we've replaced `catch {eval exec $args} res` with `catch $args res` (plus some cosmetic stuff) which will cause the arguments to be evaluated as a script *without further substitution*. You'd use it like this:

```
myeval foo bar $boo
```

Alternatively, if you're after doing substitutions within the `catch` as well, you'd be better writing this more complex version:

```
proc myeval { script } {
    info_msg "Executing Tcl command: [string trim $script]"

    set catch_res [catch [list uplevel 1 $script] res]

    if { $catch_res != 0 } {
        error_msg "Failed in command: [string trim $script]"
        error_msg "$res"
    }

    return $res
}
```

In this case, you'd call it like this:

```
myeval {
    foo bar $boo
}
```

Comment: NB: I've tried to keep the pattern of the code the same as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to modify this procedure so it runs the arguments passed as a Tcl command instead of as a Unix command, just drop the **exec**, ie. instead of `eval exec $args` just do `eval $args`.

Making a single procedure handle both Tcl and Unix commands is harder, but Tcl already does this for commands you type in tclsh or wish - it looks for a built-in command first and if it doesn't find one it then tries to run it as a Unix command.  You can turn on this behaviour in a script by doing `set ::tcl_interactive 1` - more details at [Tcl Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1793)